# PHP Syntax: $var = (new Class())->someFunction();

Tags: php, syntax

Basically what i mentioned in the title is what i am trying to do and im not sure if its possible to do or not.

I have:

```
$myClass = new Class();
$var = $myClass->someFunction();
```

But then i never use $myClass again an i could unset it to free up memory. however im trying to clean up my code at the same time and wondered if the following is valid

```
$var = (new Class())->someFunction();
```

And if its not what would you guys suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that's down as a desired feature, but not yet existing.  You'll just have to do it two-stage, `$obj = new Class(); $var = $obj->someFunction();`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always declare `someFunction()` as a `static` method.

```
$var = Class::someFunction();
```

Comment: How do you know that it is possible to make it `static`?

Comment: @Jon I have never written or seen code where is was NOT possible to redesign a method to make it static. You just have to get creative, that's all.

Comment: How about a method that uses `$this`?

Comment: @Jon `self::` will do the trick. You may have to define some extra getters and setters, but the principle still applies. Get creative. There's nothing that can't be done.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how you 'd handle the hypothetical method `public function foo() { $this->i++; }`?

Comment: @jon: because he creates the instance inline and don't want to keep the instance... Sounds like a static function can do that.

Comment: Yea, this is the route i'll probably have to go.

Comment: @jon: he creates a new instance each time, so incrementing $this->i doesn't make any sense

Comment: @WouterH: I know that a static function *can* do that. The problem is that the "you can **always** declare..." part is misleading at best. You will end up polluting the public interface of a class for no other reason than to achieve a convenient method call! IMHO it's simply better to make a free function instead.

Comment: @Jon: I know PHP is not a true OO language, but I would at least try to avoid 'free functions'. In languages like c# this isn't even possible.

Comment: @WouterH: Rationale for avoiding free functions? Because "it's not OO"? IMHO it's **much** better OO than bastardizing the public interface of a class to accommodate a deficiency of the parser.

Comment: @Matt By your previous comments it seems like you would suggest any function we find hard to access with using many lines we should just make static? What about pollution of memory through the amount of dynamic objects you are having to actually initialise so you can just get to one static constrcutor or something similar? Call me weird but I personally don't like the idea of just adding "make it static" as a solution to universal problems.

Comment: @Sammaye I'm pretty sure that *in this case* static is what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's no native way to do it

**But**

You can achieve what you want to do with a factory method.

```
class a {
    public static create() {
        return new self();
    }
    //....
}

$something = a::create()->foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$var = (new Class())->someFunction();
```

I believe this is perfectly valid syntax as of php 5.4.

As can be seen here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Yep, looks as if you are right... "  Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().  " - php.net ... However our production server is not up to 5.4 yet :/

Comment: @MichaelLynch Slap the server admins and tell them to get moving! :P

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible in versions < PHP 5.4.0

In PHP >= 5.4.0 you can de-reference arrays and use the syntax you listed above.

That said, from your description it sounds like you want a `static` function.

Comment: Damnit, I thought it was but when I tested via CLI it didn't work - turns out I have 5.3.13 which is the default with OSX Lion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call a method on a new object, but it is only supported in PHP >= 5.4

```
class Test {
   public function hello() {
    return "hello";
   }
} 

$var = (new Test())->hello();

echo $var; // prints hello
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a not valid syntax. But why don't you just reuse the variable that you assigned your object to?

```
$var = new Class();
$var = $var->someFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can also use the $myClass in pretty much every instance where you need a return value or iteration. Example:

```
foreach($myClass->fetchUsers() as $user){
}

if($myClass->userLoggedIn()){
}
```

Alot more nifty than doing a

```
$var = $myClass->fetchUsers();
foreach($var as $user){}
```